# How to slice using Keras Lambda Layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create sentence vectors for a text classification model by extracting the word with the largest norm (using that word to represent the sentence). Below is part of my Keras code:

```
Text = Input(shape=(30,))
sentence_mat = Embedding(10000, 300, input_length=30)(Text)
Norms = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(K.square(x), axis=-1))(sentence_mat)
Largest_idx = Lambda(lambda x: K.argmax(x))(Norms)
Largest = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather_nd(x, Largest_idx))(sentence_mat)
Output = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(Largest)
```

However, the following error is produced:

```
File "C:/Users/Ken/Desktop/Testing/model.py", line 39, in <module>
   Output = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(Largest)

File "C:/Users/Ken/Wheels/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 463, in __call__
   self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))

File "C:/Users/Ken/keras/layers/core.py", line 888, in build
   assert len(input_shape) >= 2

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Which I do not understand why this is so. Can someone please explain this to me?

It would be better if there is a solution using a Keras approach that does not directly involve Tensorflow.

Comment: Can you post the full tracelog please?

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have added the tracelog.

Comment: It appears you didn't specify the `input_shape` in the first layer declaration

Comment: I actually did specify the input length. I have added the input layer for clarity.

Comment: try specifying `input_shape` in addition to `input_length`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? My guess is that there is an issue with the layer involving `tf.gather_nd`. If there is a Keras way of slicing a tensor according to the indices output by `Largest_idx`, I would be keen to know. Specifying `input_shape` has not helped.